# Loading external scripts within angular html views

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have signed up to a paid version of Polldaddy and was provided this script tag (minus the proper id).

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="http://static.polldaddy.com/p/0000000.js"></script>
```

This script has to be loaded within a div in a view of mine - and it is not working. Does angular have an issue with loading scripts within a view? Is it possible? If so, could you help me understand how to do it please?

Let me know if you need more info.

Thanks

Comment: do you want to load script from partial..then Simply it won't possible

Comment: Yes, I wanted to load a script element within a view html. Why is this not possible and is there a workaround?

Comment: do look at this, using directive..I'm not sure https://gist.github.com/endorama/7369006

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't load a script inside an Angular app due the Angular [script](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/script) directive, so you need to create your own directive.
Something like this:

```
function polldaddy() {
    var injectScript = function(element) {
        var scriptTag = angular.element(document.createElement('script'));
        scriptTag.attr('charset', 'utf-8');
        scriptTag.attr('src', 'http://static.polldaddy.com/p/0000000.js');
        element.append(scriptTag);
    };

    return {
        link: function(scope, element) {
            injectScript(element);
        }
    };
}

angular
    .module('myApp')
    .directive('polldaddy', polldaddy);
```

and then in your HTML:

```
<div polldaddy></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply - this unfortunately does nothing :(

Comment: @CarlTaylor1989 you're right, I didn't test the code, sorry. Now I'm sure it works, sorry again.

Comment: Thank you that works. However I have a separate issue now with angular not liking the cross origin domain script! I believe there is no way around that hmmm...