# Checkout.com payment method is working on index.html but not in inner html pages with state ui-routing(angularjs)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, payment-gateway, checkout

I am trying to integrate checkout payment gateway with angularJS.
Code is working perfectly on index.html but not on inner ui-routing pages.

Documentation of payment checkout is given here: https://docs.checkout.com/getting-started/checkout-js-v2/display-options

```
<form class="payment-form" method="POST" action="https://merchant.com/successUrl">
  <script >
    window.CKOConfig = {
      publicKey: 'pk_test_6ff46046-30af-41d9-bf58-929022d2cd14',
      customerEmail: 'user@email.com',
      appMode: 'lightbox',
      value: 100,
      currency: 'EUR',
      renderMode:  0
    };
  </script>
  <script type="application/javascript" ng-src="https://cdn.checkout.com/v2/sandbox/js/checkout.js"></script>
</form>
```

Please help.

Comment: Can you provide `console errors` on the involved pages `but not on inner ui-routing pages.` It's hard to guess what's going on.

Comment: @masterpreenz there are no console errors. I am guessing , problem is with ui-routing.

Comment: `<script>` tag usage is disallowed on `ng templates` so you need to improvise. When initializing the directive create the `<script>` tag using Javascript then append it from there. More info [loading-external-scripts-within-angular-html-views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30102299/loading-external-scripts-within-angular-html-views)

Comment: @masterpreenz I have tried this too. Its not working

Comment: Cross Origin error when appending? It just means they `the checkout` prohibits such action. To _improvise_  though it's untested and fresh from my mind, you can just actually put the checkout script in `index.html` then dynamically moving the checkout template using [$.appendTo](https://www.freecodecamp.org/challenges/use-appendto-to-move-elements-with-jquery) everytime you needed it.